# Do Glycosides in plant seeds serve some other function than protecting the seeds?

Tags: plant-physiology, toxicology

Many plants have toxins like glycosides in the seeds and I think other parts of the plant and the accepted reason for this I believe is to discourage animals that ingest the seeds from digesting theses seeds -- the goal is for the animals to eat the fruit and disperse the seeds where they can subsequently grow. (The seed has not just toxins but also very tough shells often as in stone fruit like cherries and peaches.)

My question is whether these toxins when the plant begins to grow have some other biological function?

Comment: There are a lot of different glycosides with many functions. you may need to be more specific.

Comment: @John -- i am asking if any toxic compound in the seed has some function beyond protecting the seed from being eaten.